# Unable to prove that a statement is an equivalent form of the Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The exercise 22  page 158 of *Elements of Set Theory* by B. Enderton is the following:

> Show that the following statement is another equivalent version of the axiom of choice: For any set $A$ there is a function $F$ with $\text{dom }F=\bigcup A$ and such that $x\in F(x)\in A$ for all $x\in\bigcup A$.

The versions of the axiom of choice that I know for the moment are:

> [image]

(although the Cardinal comparability and Zorn's lemma were stated as well, the author didn't prove yet that they're equivalent to the Axiom of Choice)

and the following form: (Exercise 18 in the same page)

> [image]

I proved that AC III implies the statement of the exercise as follows:

Let $A$ be a set
According to AC III there exists a function $f:\mathcal{P}A\setminus\{\emptyset\}\to A$ such as $\forall X\in\mathcal{P}A\setminus\{\emptyset\},\,f(X)\in X$.

Let

\begin{align*}
g:&\bigcup A\,\,\to \mathcal{P}A\setminus\{\emptyset\}\\
&x \quad\quad\mapsto\{a\in A\mid x\in a\}
\end{align*}

$g$ is a well defined function/

Let $F=f\circ g$. Then $\text{dom }F=\text{dom }g=\bigcup A$.

Let $x\in\bigcup A$. $F(x)=f(g(x))=f\left(\{a\in A\mid x\in a\}\right)$. Thus $F(x)\in\{a\in A\mid x\in a\}$. Thus $x\in F(x)\in A$.$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

I couldn't prove the other way. I had two ideas:( $F:\bigcup A\to A$ such that $\forall a\in\bigcup A,\,a\in F(a)\in A$)

1) We could try to construct an "inverse" of $F$. But $F$ isn't necessarily injective nor surjective. Thus such a construction would require the axiom of choice.

2) We could consider $f=F\circ g$ where $g:\,A\to \bigcup\bigcup A$ and $F:\,\bigcup\bigcup A\to\bigcup A$ but I couldn't find a suitable $g$.

Could you please help me? Thanks you in advance!

Comment: multiplicative axiom ​ ​

Comment: Do you mean that I should prove the multiplicative axiom? I tried to do so but I failed. According to the statement of the exercise there is a function $F:\bigcup_{i\in I}H(i)\to\{H(i)\mid i\in I\}$ that satisfies $x\in F(x)\in\bigcup_{i\in I}H(i)$. However nothing ensures that $F$ is surjective. Even if that was the case, for each $i\in I$, we will have to use the axiom of choice to justify that we can choose an element which image by $F$ is $H(i)$.

Comment: Yes. ​ You should use Exercise 18, rather than whatever exercise your comment uses. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Exercise 18 is the statement "For any set $\mathcal{A}$ whose members are nonempty sets, there is a function $f$ with domain $\mathcal{A}$ such that $f(X)\in X$ for all $X$ in $\mathcal{A}$", so what I tried to prove (as I wrote in my question) is that the statement of exercise 22 implies the statement of exercise 18 but I failed to.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that when you've already "proved that AC III implies the statement of the exercise"? ​ ​

Comment: I should prove that $\text{AC}\Leftrightarrow \text{Exercise 22}$. I proved that  $\text{AC}\Rightarrow \text{Exercise 22}$, so what remains is to prove that $ \text{Exercise 22}\Rightarrow \text{AC}$ and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Oh, yeah. ​ I suppose for _that_, I'd [disjointify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union#Example) the relation R's domain and range and then convert it to a set of [doubletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: :o I never knew about disjoint unions thank you for that information. I tried your idea but I couldn't prove $\text{AC}$: Let $R$ be a relation, $A_0=\text{dom } R$ and $A_1=\text{ran }R$. Let $S=\text{ran }d$ where $\text{dom }d=A_0\sqcup A_1$ and $d(x,y)=\{x,y\}$ (that's how I converted it to a set of doubletons as you told me to do). We should construct a function $F\subseteq R$ which domain is $A_0$. Let $f$ be the function described in $\text{Exercise 22}$ (with $A=S$). The problem is that I couldn't find how to use it.

Comment: What you did only uses R's domain and range, rather than anything else about R. ​ ​

Comment: Indeed but I thinked about it. On the set $S$ we get a new relation $R'$ such that $\{x,y\}R'\{z,t\}$ iff $\exists a\in\{x,y\},\,\exists b\in\{z,t\},\,aRb$ (and it follows that $0\in\{x,y\}$ and that $1\in\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Would you give me time to think about that? I read answers in the link provided in "my answer" and I learned tricks there. I'd like to see if I'll be able to use them in your case :)

Comment: @RickyDemer I'm going to use the trick of IainM in the link where my question has an answer (that trick is powerful!):  Let $R$ be a relation. Let $h:\,\text{dom }R\to\mathcal{P}\,\text{ran R}$ such as $h(x)=\{y\in\text{ran }R\mid xRy\}$. Let $S=\{(a,b)\in h(\text{dom }R\times\text{ran }R\mid b\in a\}$ (with $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\})$. Let $\pi_2:h(\text{dom }R\times\text{ran }R \to\text{ran }R$ such as $\pi_2(a,b)=b$. Let $F$ be the function described in Exercise 22 with range $\bigcup S$. Then let $f:\text{dom }R\to\text{ran }R$ such as $f(x)=\pi_2\circ F(\{h(x)\})$...

Comment: We have $\{h(x)\}\in F(\{x\})=(a,b)\in S$. Clearly we must have $a=h(x)$. Since $(h(x),b)\in S$, we have $b\in h(x)$. Thus $xRb$ with $b=\pi_2((h(x),b))=f(x)$.